# Oracle 11g unpivot very slow - low performance

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

My query's `unpivot` query performance is very low, it runs very slowly and takes around 11s to execute, while the `base` query that it's based on takes around 60ms to execute.

The `base` query is complex, with several joins, but it returns only a few rows.

Unpivot operates on ~7 group-by columns and unpivots around 40 columns.

Explain query plan shows no details, only that the cost of unpivot is very high.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL statements for your table, DML statements for your sample data, your query and the explain plan. Otherwise you are preventing other people from being able to offer answers to this question as "Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: I'm providing a possible solution to an otherwise ungooglable problem; I spent hours trying to solve it. The question's already highly indexed in google and it gives people a possible solution to a specific (title) problem. And a MCVE would take hours and I couldn't possibly expect it to actually show the problem, as Oracle's query analyzer's bound to do something differently there than on a large production database with gathered statistics. I don't care if you close the question or I lose rep or whatever, because I believe that if there's 1 person whom I help it's worth it. For developers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try is to use `WITH` clause for the `base` query.

Instead of

```
SELECT * from (SELECT my_data, ...) UNPIVOT (...)
```

Try

```
WITH base as (select my_data, ...) select * from base UNPIVOT (...)
```

In my case it reduced query time by a factor of 10.

Comment: If you are going to self-answer this question then please provide a [MCVE] to back up your assertions.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am interested to know why it is working?